# Is my financial plan for buying a house logically sound

Tags: mortgage, interest, first-time-home-buyer, rental-property, new-zealand

- All money is in NZD, all calculations done **Weekly**. Linked house is just example.
- [House](http://www.trademe.co.nz/property/residential-property-for-sale/auction-635082505.htm) in North Shore, Auckland, New Zealand. $600K
- 30 year [Mortgage](https://www.asb.co.nz/section309.aspx) with ASB, 430K loaned at 5.75% variable, (170K down)

Loan repayment figures:

```
Repayment required: $750
Proportion in interest: $475 :  ($430,000 x (0.0575/52))
Proportion in principal: $275 : (total-interest)
```

Incoming rent figures: (estimate)

```
Gross rent: $600 (Caters a bit of down-time)
net rent after tax: $450
```

Other figures:

```
$130 implicit revenue, from $475 interest, tax deductible.
```

Final calculations to show benefit in my favour (of making this decision)

```
$750 total, to be paid.
+$50 (estimate of home-owner related costs)
-$450 net rent
-$130 implicit revenue from interest tax deduct 475 (27% of 475)
-$200 rent I would have paid, if was renting somewhere else
-$275 proportion of payment that is principal (my money anyway)

=-$255. (I.E $255 per week to be benefited from buying this house)
```

Comment: Are you sure your mortgage compounds weekly? I can see why you did the calculations the way you did, (and my wife is a Kiwi... I thought most loans over there are fortnightly.) Increasing the compounding to be more frequent makes you pay more interest. I would also really avoid getting into an adjustable mortgage right now if you can at all avoid it.

Comment: You show incoming rent, but also rent you 'would have' paid. So is this house for you to live in, or a rental? Is there property tax? And - not sure what the $50 is, but a house can easily cost up to 1%/yr in maintenance over time. Not every year, not when brand new, but some years in, it gets to that level. $4000/yr might be right for this house.

Comment: Don't the payments of $750 per week reduce the principal owed at all? Your second weekly payment should have slightly less of interest (because the principal has reduced by $275) and slightly more of principal paid off, no? The lower interest reduces the tax benefit too.  Also, why is it a **30-year** mortgage since you will be paying it off in about 17.5 years as discussed in a different question of yours? Will the bank still have a death-grip on the property during the 12.5 years after the loan has been fully paid off?

Comment: Looks like what we found some big flaws, this is great!. Ok yes, 

1. Yes, it compounds weekly, so I should have calculated it fortnightly, so that's one mistake! 

2. It's a rental, but I will live in it as well, so will fill 3 rooms, and live in 1.

3. I'm not sure if there's property tax or not, I don't believe there is!. The $50 was an estimate, wow 1%, ok thank you, that is a bit of a scary amount!

4. On the ASB calculator, I typed in 30 years, & it gave me this amount, so I just assumed it would take 30 years. Maybe their online calculator is wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a rental, this is not an ideal set of numbers. You manage to show a $255 'gain' but $275 is from payment to principal. So, from the start, you're out $20/wk.

This ignores the $170K down payment, which has an opportunity cost, however you calculate it. You can assign the same rate as the mortgage, and it's nearly $10K/yr. Or the rate you feel your choice of stock market or alternate investment would rise. Either way, you can't ignore this money.

Your mortgage rate isn't fixed.
A 1% rise and it would jump to $1663 ($842/week)

Ideally, a rental property is cash positive without counting principal paydown or even the tax refund. It's a risky proposition to buy and count on everything going right. I didn't mean to scare you off with "1%" but you should research the costs of repair and maintenance. Last year my Heat/AC system needed replacement. US$10K. This year, it's time to paint, and replace rotting trim, $7000.

In the US we have property tax that can range from 1-2% of the house value. If you don't have this tax, that's great, just please confirm this.

Comment: +1 You might want to tell the OP about depreciation of rental property too as something to take into account.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - OP is in New Zealand. I'm lucky they use the same numbers system, and mortgage amortization is pretty universal. Although - a search http://www.ird.govt.nz/income-tax-individual/different-income-taxed/rental-income/inc-invest-property/ mentions depreciation. So yes, we just mentioned it. I might edit my response as well. Thanks, as always.